# What can I say instead of [go miles]

Tags: expressions

I want to say in my personal statement "At the time, it gave me hope, optimism and certainty that this is what I want to do and that I’m going to [go miles] in my career.

Comment: It vs. this & gave vs. want and go*ing* ?

Comment: Both "go far in my career" and "go a long way in my career" are normal, idiomatic phrases for this.

Comment: Definitely, **go far** in my career.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can say "At the time, it gave me hope, optimism and certainty that this is what I want to do and that I’m going to [***succeed***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/succeed) in my career"